# Why the order of application of properties of Wilcoxon Rank-Sum makes a difference

Tags: nonparametric, inference, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

Suppose I am calculating the p-value of a Wilcoxon Rank-Sum test where $W_s = 23$, $n=4$ and $m=5$ suppose that we have:

$pvalue = P(W_s \ge  23 | H_0)$

The way I manage to get to the right answer is to use the property that $W_s$ is simetrical around $n*((n+m)+1)/2$ and get:

- As $n=4$ and $m=5$, $n*((n+m)+1)/2 = 20$

$P(W_s \ge  20 + 3 | H_0 ) = P(W_s \le  20 - 3 | H_0 )$

and then find $W_{x,y}$ using that $W_{x,y} = W_s - n*(n+1)/2$:

- As $n=4$, $n*(n+1)/2 = 10$

$P(W_s \le  17 | H_0 ) = P(W_x,y \le  7) = 0.2778$

However, if I just apply the second property directly I get a different, wrong result:

- As $n=4$, $n*(n+1)/2 = 10$

$pvalue = P(W_s \ge  23 | H_0) = P(W_{x,y} \ge  13) = 0.20$

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that I made a mistake, I was calculating $P(Wx,y>13)$ and not $P(Wx,y \ge 13)$. The properties pointed out by me are valid regardless of the order that you apply them.

Notice that the big problem was that I was comparing

```
pwilcox(13,4,5,lower.tail=FALSE)
```

With:

```
pwilcox(7,4,5,lower.tail=TRUE)
```

In R, and as `lower.tail = FALSE` implies strictly greater, and not greater or equals to, I was getting a mistake.

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it? You can also turn it into a comment. On the other hand, if you think this is the full answer to your question, you can accept it by clicking the check mark to its left below the vote total.